# jqGrid Advanced Search fail to show new columns added by the columnchooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

After I open the advanced filter modal, if I go and add an additional column using the columnchooser, the new added column is not shown in the advanced search dialog.

I know about the recreateFilter, but I need the search dialog to keep it's current configuration/filter until the user clear on reset.  I can't afford to reset the filter each time user open the dialog.

So what I'm looking is a way to reflect the changes from the column chooser into the advanced search WITHOUT reseting the filter.

The recreateForm is not a member in the searchGrid function, and is not working.

Any idea, or a way to overcome the problem is welcome.

(One idea I have in mind, if this is a bug, was to set recreateFilter=true only when the user click on reset, and set it back to false onSearch, so at least user will have some decent option to reload the dialog, but I don't know how to achieve that, and prefer a cleaner way if possible).

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: I'm using version 4.7.1.